# Loop over json list generated by oracle procedure

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a loop over a json list  generated by oracle procedure:

Control:

```
public JsonResult GetLOVDivCount()
{
    return Json(SearchRep.GetDivCount(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Model:

```
public static GetLovListModel GetDivCount()
{
    var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
    p.Add("p_output", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    string spName = "p_get_div_count";
    GetLovListModel glist = new GetLovListModel();
    using (var grid = DB.GetMultiGrid(spName, p: p))
    {
        glist.GetDivCount = grid.Read<GetDivCount>().ToList();
    }
    return glist;
}
```

View:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '@Url.Action("GetLOVDivCount")',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        **jQuery.each(result, function(key,val){
            $("#tDivCount").last().append("<tr><td>" + result + "</td><td>New row</td><td>New row</td></tr>");**
        })
    }
});
```

But the table is showing only null data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

remove last()

```
$("#tDivCount").append("<tr><td>" + val+ "</td><td>New row</td><td>New row</td></tr>")
```

NOTE: remove last() in selector and also check **result** value in console ..what it will be print, **result** is a array don't put directly ,use value or key while appending

Comment: The issue not in .append or .last ! it works fine. the issue is the result is showing null data!  the rows appended but with text [object Object]

Comment: it is null ,the each function wont work, and also u tried to append result,value directly ,use val or key

Comment: I've use all possible values, items, index with no success. result['DivDesc'] result[key]['DivDesc] .................. the console is showing all the available divisions on the DB

Comment: can you display your result value in fiddle or somewhere else

Comment: if I put key I got: null, null, ......., [object Object] for getDivCount. val will give the model list in the project GetDivCount,...,.... in additional to the other models.  it seems the each function is running over all models list in the project.

Comment: Please make it fiddle of your result value , with out seeing result object it s hard to give solution

Comment: this is the result <br>Divsion Description Stud # %<br>
null - GetSites New row New row<br>
null - GetDivisions New row New row<br>
null - GetBlocks New row New row<br>
[object Object] - GetDivCount New row New row<br>

Comment: i did't say like this .. i want to print console this value [object Object]  **result**

Comment: Not sure if I can make it fiddle as it's a database procedure, let me make it easy for you: I want to read oracle SYS_REFCURSOR output from a procedure and display the reult in a table

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:) first I should specify the model name with the result result.GetDivCount

to show the value: val['DivCount']

```html
  success: function (result) {
                 DivJason = result;
                 jQuery.each(result.GetDivCount, function (i, val) {
                     $("#tDivCount").last().append("<tr><td>" + val['DivDesc'] + "</td><td>" + val['DivCount'] + "</td><td>New row</td></tr>");
                 })
             }
```

Thanks for the help.